# problem creating a reusable filtered table using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a reusable table component where I can only pass down as props the **data** and the **filters** and it will already handle most of the work for me. However, right now, **I am hardcoding the select variables into the Table state** and if I am to create another table with different filters I would have to create another component for that. And that's not viable in anyway.

right now I have a **master component** that hold the data and filter and passes down to Table component, like that:

```
class Master extends React.Component {
   listHotels: [
      createObject('BlueTree','05-02-2015','ativo', 'Vinhedo', 'São Paulo'),
      createObject('Inner','07-08-2016','inativo', 'Belo Horizonte', 'Minas Gerais'),
      createObject('Teste','05-02-2017','ativo', 'Teresina', 'Piauí'),
      createObject('hello','05-02-2015','ativo', 'Osasco', 'São Paulo'),
      createObject('Inner','07-08-2016','inativo', 'Lavras', 'Minas Gerais'),
      createObject('Teste','05-02-2017','inativo', 'Barras', 'Piauí'),
      createObject('xiaomi','05-02-2015','inativo', 'Indaiatuba', 'São Paulo'),
      createObject('Inner','07-08-2016','ativo', 'Pedrinhas', 'Minas Gerais'),
      createObject('Teste','05-02-2017','ativo', 'Esperantina', 'Piauí'),
    ].sort((a, b) => (a.id < b.id ? -1 : 1)),
    selectFilter: [
      { id: 1, type: 'Name', options}, 
      { id: 2, type: 'Data', options},
      { id: 3, type: 'Cidade', options},
      { id: 4, type: 'Estado', options},
      { id: 5, type: 'PMS', options},
    ],
}
```

and then I call the table component on render function

```
 <Table listHotels={listHotels} toggleList={this.toggleList} selectFilter={selectFilter}></Table>
```

On the **Table component** I have the state to keep track of the filter select options as you can see below(status, pms, state...):

```
state = {
    page: 0,
    rowsPerPage: 5,
    query: '',
    filter: [],
    status: null,
    pms: null,
    state: null,
    city: null,
    name: null,
    isLoading: false
  };
```

And whenever the option is selected I create an API call to hit the back end and respond with some data to fill the state's filter property.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    const { status, pms, state, city, page, rowsPerPage } = this.state;

    const filterOptions = [];

    if (status !== null){
      filterOptions.push({name: "status", value: status});
    }

    if (pms !== null){
      filterOptions.push({name: "pms", value: pms});
    }

    if (state !== null){
      filterOptions.push({name: "estado", value: state});
    }

    if (city !== null){
      filterOptions.push({name: "cidade", value: city});
    }

    if(filterOptions.length !== 0){
      const url = createAPICall(filterOptions, page, rowsPerPage);
      //call api and set it to the filter property
    }
```

However, the way the component is right now is not reusable. If I want to create another table with other filters, I would have to change the state to hold the filter variables and also to create the API url.

How can I make this more dynamic?

Comment: Where do you set states from props?

Comment: I am not doing this yet. trying to find out how to do it first

Comment: Can you share your codes on codesandbox? I want to see like filter data types. What's the `options`? Where you take city,pms values? Please share working example on codesandbox with one table.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you want to make the filter types more flexible. part of the issue is you manually list them out in state and table. start by bundling your filter types into an object to pass through from master (or extract them from selectFilter).

When you set state, set `filters: {...parse filters here...}`.

next in componentDidUpdate, you don't want to be manually listing each `if` statement, you want to iterate over your filters obj definition, adding an `if` per obj key in each loop. When values are updated in your form/table, push the key value in your state object, not the individual values like you have now.
i.e.

```
   const { status, pms, state, city, page, rowsPerPage } = this.state;
```

would look more like

```
   const { filters, page, rowsPerPage } = this.state;
```

Comment: how do I setState from props? should i use componentWillMount() and create another property?